# How to add 1) add unique identifier every 3 rows of data frame

Tags: r

My data frame

```
plate  phase  score
A      1      1
A      2      1
A      3      2

A      1      1
A      2      1
A      3      2


A      1      1
A      2      1
A      3      2



B      1      1
B      2      1
B      3      4

B      1      1
B      2      1
B      3      4
```

Generate a unique identifier for every 3 rows of an ordered data frame (there are duplicate rows across each triplet; however, they require different identifiers despite being identical). That is each ordered triplet needs to have a unique identifier. Thank you for any help!!

Here's the (what I want it to look like):

```
plate  phase  score  tripletID
A      1      1      A.1 
A      2      1      A.1
A      3      2      A.1
A      1      1      A.2
A      2      1      A.2 
A      3      2      A.2
A      1      1      A.3
A      2      1      A.3
A      3      2      A.3
B      1      1      B.1
B      2      1      B.1
B      3      2      B.1
B      1      1      B.2
B      2      1      B.2
B      3      2      B.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(plate) %>%
 mutate(tripletID = paste(plate, gl(n()/3, 3), sep = "."))

   plate phase score tripletID
   <chr> <int> <int> <chr>    
 1 A         1     1 A.1      
 2 A         2     1 A.1      
 3 A         3     2 A.1      
 4 A         1     1 A.2      
 5 A         2     1 A.2      
 6 A         3     2 A.2      
 7 A         1     1 A.3      
 8 A         2     1 A.3      
 9 A         3     2 A.3      
10 B         1     1 B.1      
11 B         2     1 B.1      
12 B         3     2 B.1      
13 B         1     1 B.2      
14 B         2     1 B.2      
15 B         3     2 B.2
```

If there could be a scenario that you won't have three cases for the last ID:

```
df %>%
 group_by(plate) %>%
 mutate(tripletID = paste(plate, gl(ceiling(n()/3), 3, n()), sep = "."))
```

Comment: This works (thanks!!), but what if the data frame is not ordered as I had originally asked? I updated the question to illustrate this (Goal #1).

Comment: The posts are usually based on the assumptions shown in the question. If you change radically the assumptions, then it is better to create a completely new question. People can then supply answers tailored specifically for the given situation.

Comment: Hi tmfmnk, thank you for advising on the proper question format -- makes sense, I will do that

Answer (score 2):

We can use `ave` in base R and create a sequence column for each `plate`, divide it by 3 and round up using `ceiling`

```
with(df, paste0(plate, ".", ceiling(ave(phase, plate, FUN = seq_along)/3)))

#[1] "A.1" "A.1" "A.1" "A.2" "A.2" "A.2" "A.3" "A.3" "A.3" "B.1" "B.1" "B.1" 
#    "B.2" "B.2" "B.2"
```

Using `dplyr`, that could be done as :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(plate) %>%
  mutate(temp = paste0(plate, ".", ceiling(row_number() / 3)))
```

and in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, temp := paste0(plate, ".", ceiling(seq_len(.N)/3)), plate]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rep` to get unique identifiers for groups of 3 like:

```
rep(seq_len(nrow(x)/3), each=3)
 [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5
```

In case you want the combination shown in the question you can use `ave` for grouping by `plate` and use `paste` and `rep` to get the unique identifiers.

```
ave(x$plate, x$plate, FUN=function(x) {
       paste(x, rep(seq_len(length(x)/3), each=3), sep=".")})
# [1] "A.1" "A.1" "A.1" "A.2" "A.2" "A.2" "A.3" "A.3" "A.3" "B.1" "B.1" "B.1"
#[13] "B.2" "B.2" "B.2"
```

or using `split` and `lapply`

```
unlist(lapply(split(x$plate, x$plate), FUN=function(x) {
       paste(x, rep(seq_len(length(x)/3), each=3),sep=".")}))
```

Data:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="plate  phase  score
A      1      1
A      2      1
A      3      2
A      1      1
A      2      1
A      3      2
A      1      1
A      2      1
A      3      2
B      1      1
B      2      1
B      3      2
B      1      1
B      2      1
B      3      2")
```