# Convert values to NA based on first value of Group in R

Tags: r

I am trying to group a dataframe into groups of 3, by column. So group 1 is column 1-3, group 2 is column 4-6 and so on.
Then I want to iterate over the rows based on the group.
I want to check if the first value in each group per row is 'NA'.
If it is 'NA', all values in that group should be turned to 'NA'. If it is not NA, values should be left as they are.

An example df:

```
df <- data.frame(col_1 = c(1,2,3,NA,3,2,1),
             col_2 = c(1,3,2,4,3,2,1),
             col_3 = c(1,2,3,4,3,2,1),
             col_4 = c(NA,2,3,4,3,2,1),
             col_5 = c(2,2,3,4,3,2,1),
             col_6 = c(3,2,3,4,3,2,1))
```

the output i want:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(col_1 = c(1,2,3,NA,3,2,1),
               col_2 = c(1,3,2,NA,3,2,1),
               col_3 = c(1,2,3,NA,3,2,1),
               col_4 = c(NA,2,3,4,3,2,1),
               col_5 = c(NA,2,3,4,3,2,1),
               col_6 = c(NA,2,3,4,3,2,1))
```

I tried to use 'group_by()' and 'mutate()' but got nowhere. Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using `rowwise`?

Comment: Please explain how a group is or should be defined, I can't see any.

Comment: I think you need to split the `col_*` by 3 and replace the value of other two based on where `NA` of the first `col_*` of three is located. then you could join them together

Comment: I tried to clarify my question. What I mean is column 1-3 is the first group, column 4-6 the second and so on. Then I want to iterate over rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help. Groups are defined by `rep(1:(ncol(df)/3), each=3)` and this has to be adjusted if more groups/rows are present.

```
library(dplyr)

as_tibble(cbind(ID = c(rep(1:(ncol(df)/3), each=3)), t(df))) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("V"), ~ replace(., is.na(.x[1]), NA)), .by = ID) %>% 
  select(-ID) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  data.frame(row.names = c()) %>% 
  setNames(colnames(df))
  col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5 col_6
1     1     1     1    NA    NA    NA
2     2     3     2     2     2     2
3     3     2     3     3     3     3
4    NA    NA    NA     4     4     4
5     3     3     3     3     3     3
6     2     2     2     2     2     2
7     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to implement this, but for some reason it only works for the first 3 cols with me. The second (and in my longer actual code) and further groups of cols still have values even though the first value in that group is NA and thus all values in that group and row should be NA.

Comment: Only apply `as_tibble(cbind(ID = c(rep(1:(ncol(df)/3), each=3)), t(df)))` and check variable `ID`. If it's not the groups you want you have to adjust `rep(1:(ncol(df)/3), each=3)`. Do you want me to explain in the answer what that does?

Comment: Hi, thanks you so much for your answer. I just tried it on my larger dataset and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a another option:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

id_help <- df |> 
  colnames() |> 
  as_tibble() |>  
  # credits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58212957/how-to-add-1-add-unique-identifier-every-3-rows-of-data-frame
  mutate(id = as.numeric(gl(ceiling(n()/3), 3, n()))) |> 
  rename(name = value)

df |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('col')) |> 
  left_join(id_help) |> 
  dplyr::group_split(id) |> 
  map(~.x |> 
        select(-id) |> 
        group_by(name) |> 
        # id needed for pivot wider
        mutate(id = row_number()) |> 
        pivot_wider(id_cols = everything(), names_from = name, 
                    values_from = value) |> 
        select(-id) |> 
        rowwise() |>
        mutate(check = any(across(1, ~ is.na(.)))) |>
        mutate(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(exclude == TRUE, yes = NA, .x))) |>
        select(-check) |> 
        ungroup()) |> 
  bind_cols()
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 7 × 6
  col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5 col_6
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1    NA    NA    NA
2     2     3     2     2     2     2
3     3     2     3     3     3     3
4    NA    NA    NA     4     4     4
5     3     3     3     3     3     3
6     2     2     2     2     2     2
7     1     1     1     1     1     1
```